# Metodos y atributos

Tags: java, java-util-scanner, instancias

por esta vez tengo dos preguntas muy pero muy sencillas que ni llevan codigo, sino es algo conceptual pero que mejor que preguntarles a los expertos.

Solo quisiera saber si en mi clase principal, la que utiliza el método main, si importo un paquete como lo es java.util.Scanner, Scanner puede ser considerado un método,atributo o algo por el estilo de mi clase principal o no?

por otro lado, que es almacenar multiples instancias? guardar muchos objetos en algun arreglo o a que se refiere?

en verdad apreciaría mucho su ayuda!

Comment: 1. No. `import` se usa para importar librerías en ese contexto. Significa que al importar `Scanner` (o cualquier otra clase) podrás usar todos los métodos/atributos/propiedades de esa clase a los que tengas acceso. 2. Almacenar múltiples instancias es guardar más de una instancia de una (o de varias clases) en alguna parte. Sea en el contexto de la misma clase en que crees las intancias, sea en un array, en un map o en cualquier otro objeto. Una instancia de una clase es todo aquello que crees con `new LaClase()` o que recibas de otra parte...

Answer (score 0):

- La ruta `java.utils.Scanner`, lo que indica es que, dentro de los
  paquetes java que dentro contiene a utils, hay una biblioteca llamada
  Scanner, de la que tú harás uso. Es dicha biblioteca la que contendrá
  métodos y atributos de los que tú harás uso.
- Según como lo escribes, sí, puede ser tener varios objetos y puede
  ser que con decir "almacenar múltiples instancias" se haga referencia
  a ponerlos en un array, arraylist, cualquier estructura en memoria o
  de manera persistente en una bd o en archivos.